# how to change style *ngFor (loop) angular 2

Tags: css, angular

I have made a group of checkboxes with *ngFor and I want if I click on each of them color of them change and if click again color returns to the previous color:

```
<div *ngFor="let chekb of amenities" class="checkbox col-md-4 nopadding">
<label>
  <input class="removebox" type="checkbox" (change)="changecheckbox($event)" name="checked" [(ngModel)]="chekb.checked">
  {{chekb.title}}
</label>
</div>
```

component:

```
public amenities: checkBoxClass[] = [
{title:"pool",value:"pool" ,checked:false},
{title:"parking",value:"parking", checked:false}
]
```

Actually it is a checkbox to choose any of them may be one or two or more.
How can I change color of them by click on them?
Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to toggle between colors or random any number colors?

Comment: checkout awesome bootstrap checkboxes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@component({
  ...
  ...

 /****** added style  ******/
  style:[
    `
       mycolor:{background : red}              
    `
  ]

})    


<div *ngFor="let chekb of amenities;let i=index"           //modified
      class="checkbox col-md-4 nopadding">
          <label [class.mycolor]="chekb.checked">          //modified
              <input class="removebox" 
                     type="checkbox" 
                     (change)="changecheckbox($event)" 
                     name="checked" 
                     [(ngModel)]="chekb.checked">

                             {{chekb.title}}

            </label>
</div>
```